# Looking at private parts for pregnancy

Tags: children, awrah, pregnancy

In the country where I stay, if a woman is pregnant and she goes to hospital, she may be assigned a male gynecologist. The only way to be sure to have a female gynecologist is to look for a private practitioner that is  very expensive.

These are my questions: Per fiqh, in this situation, if a man cannot afford a female practitioner:

1. Is he allowed to make his wife pregnant or should he use
   contraceptive methods so that his wife doesn't fall pregnant so that
   a man does not see her private parts.
2. Is it not mustahab for him not to have children until he becomes financially able to get her a female practioner because if his wife
   gets pregnant, a man will see her private parts

My questions is based on two pieces of knowledge. First, as far as I know, looking at the awra of a woman is not allowed by a man unless the woman's life is in danger. Secondly, as far as I know, having baby is not obligatory.

Comment: W,r,t your second observation in the last para, having children is definitely recommended  -- Abu Dawood (2050) narrated that Ma’qil ibn Yasaar said: A man came to the Prophet (PBUH) & said, “I have found a woman who is of good lineage & is beautiful but she does not children. Should I marry her?” He said, “No.” Then he came again with the same question and he told him not to marry her. Then he came a third time with the same question and he said: “Marry those who are loving and fertile, for I will be proud of your great numbers before the other nations.”

Comment: I agree it is recommended but it is not fard, it is not obligatory while a woman does not have right to show her private parts unless there is a danger of life

Comment: Note that if your wife wants children you are not permitted to deny her this whish! You are even not allowed to have coitus interruptus without her permission.

Comment: @Medi1Saif Suppose if my wife wants children and I know that by doing so, she will be seen by a male gynecologist, being in a muslim minority country, the male gynecologist will be most probably a non-muslim, what does fiqh says, am I still not permitted to deny her this wish ?

Comment: Fiqh says in case of need a woman can be consult a male gynaecologist. In the hospital my wife gave birth to our three children she only twice have been examined by a male gynaecologist most of the stuff was female. The only thing which is necessary is that you as her husband and mahram are present. See also [Had to show my full am to a man](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/49723/had-to-show-my-full-arm-to-a-man/49730#49730)

Comment: If we go the question "am I still not permitted to deny her this wish ? ", then it would mean "Yes" ?

Comment: As per my understand it is "yes". Note that I doubt that in all hospitals there are only male gynaecologists so you might consider searching for one that actually has more female stuff. The matter is less complex than as you said. Also many north Africans travel to France/the USA etc. (for citizenship of the child) to give birth you may consider to do the opposite ;)

Answer (score 1):

**In presence of a mahram a physician my see what is necessary of the 'awrah of a woman**

First you must be aware that in presence of a mahram a phyisican is allowed to check a woman. As explained with more details in my answer on [Had to show my full arm to a man](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/49723/had-to-show-my-full-arm-to-a-man?noredirect=1&lq=1). This actually sets your argument of a man seeing your wife's privat parts void. I remember the moments of birth of each of my sons (I still have a picture in mind for each of them) and I'd recommend being present for this and helping the wife and giving her comfort as else she would be surrounded by strangers. The only moment when I was sent out was when she got the epidural and that was only in one case the second time I was just asked to look away if I would fear seeing it.

**The presence of a gynaecologist is generally not necessary during the birth**

Secondly the presence of a gynaecologist is normally totally unnecessary for that act of birth unless there are any complications. In Germany for the usual birth there are two or three people present the woman who gives birth, the midwife who assists, helps and guide her and the father of the child to give his wife comfort etc. A physician is only called at the end or even after the birth to check the newborn and the woman who gave birth and probably sew the perianal rupture.
Sadly since pregnancy and birth became a business and many women prefer to have caesarean instead of a natural birth or one with the aid of peridural anaesthesia the presence of normally needless physicians became more and more a luxurious must.

**It is recommended to have children and frowned upon or even haram to avoid having them**

Thirdly it is rather recommended to have children and frowned upon or even haram <sub>( in case you are afraid not being able to be in charge of them or afraid from poverty)</sub> -if it is possible- to refuse having them. While it might be necessary if there are any medical indications. See for example islamqa #[127170](https://islamqa.info/en/127170) where it says:

> It says in a statement of the Islamic Fiqh Council belonging to the Muslim World League: The Islamic Fiqh Council affirms unanimously that it is not permissible to limit the number of children in general and it is not permissible to prevent pregnancy if the reason for doing that is fear of poverty, because Allah is the Provider and Owner of great power, and there is no living creature on earth but its provision is due from Allah, or if that is for other reasons that are not acceptable according to sharee’ah.
>
> As for using means of preventing or delaying pregnancy in individual cases where real and certain harm will result from it, such as if the pregnant woman will have to give birth in a manner other than that which is usual, and she will have to have surgery to bring the child forth, in which case there is nothing in sharee’ah to prevent her doing that. The same applies if it is delayed for other legitimate shar’i or health reasons confirmed by a trustworthy Muslim doctor. Contraception becomes a must in a case where it is proven that harm would result for the mother or there is the fear that she may die, according to the opinion of a trustworthy Muslim doctor. End quote from Fatawa Islamiyyah, 3/200.

and on a similar topic fatwa islamqa #[7205](https://islamqa.info/en/7205).

**Not all hospitals have only male stuff**

Last but not least as said in my comments you may find hospitals where the majority stuff of the gynaecological hospital is female. This also should set your argument void to some extent. And you should inform yourself about the hospital and the process of birth before going there. In Germany all gynaecological hospitals have an information evening once a month where to be parents can seek information and learn about the hospital and stuff. Also note that not all physicians in non-Muslim countries are solely non-Muslims.

**Epilogue and conclusion**

Finally the view or attitude of Islam for life and giving birth is positive this means Islam even if it considers itself the last and final -true- revelation it encourages life and enjoying life as is and it doesn't encourage giving up life or having any negative attitude against life. Therefore marrying is encouraged, having children is encouraged and even if it might be the last hour labouring is encouraged:

- > ... What has happened to these people that they say so and so, whereas I observe prayer and sleep too; I observe fast and suspend observing them; I marry women also? And he who turns away from my Sunnah, he has no relation with Me.
  >   (The statment made by our prophet () taken from the long hadith of those sahaba who wanted to be as pious as the prophet (), see for example in [Sahih al-Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/67/1) and [Sahih Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim/16/6))
- > "Marry women who are loving and very prolific, for I shall outnumber the peoples by you."
  >   (See for example in [Sunan abi Dawod](https://sunnah.com/abudawud/12/5), [Sunan an-Nasa-i](https://sunnah.com/nasai/26/32) and [Sunan ibn Majah](https://sunnah.com/urn/1319200))
- > "If the Final Hour comes while you have a palm-cutting in your hands and it is possible to plant it before the Hour comes, you should plant it."
  >   (See in al-Bukjhari's [Al-Adab al-Mufrad](https://sunnah.com/urn/2304770) and also in Musnad Ahmad).

So from all of this you should know that your fear is not a reason that has enough weight to allow you to reject having children. Because you may choose a hospital where the chance of meeting a male gynaecologist is low or lower, you may inform yourself before the day of birth about the hospital and stuff, you may even consider travelling to a Muslim country or a country/location where your wife would rather be surrounded by female stuff ... so there are many walk around to solve the issue which was in first place created in your mind.

And finally be aware that staying -without necessity- or to settle in non-Muslim land is not appropriate for a Muslim based on:

> I am not responsible for any Muslim who stays among polytheists. They asked: Why, Messenger of Allah? He said: Their fires should not be visible to one another.
>   (See in [Sunan abi Dawod](https://sunnah.com/abudawud/15/169) and [Jami' at-Tirmidhi](https://sunnah.com/tirmidhi/21/67))

While it is rather allowed to go there for a purpose and come back to Muslim land.

Comment: Thanks for your answer brother, I was checking Islamqna.info on this matter at "https://islamqa.info/en/5693" and it says:  ""When a sick women needs to be uncovered (for medical treatment), preference should be given to a qualified female Muslim doctor; if such is not available, the order of preference is then a female non-Muslim doctor, a male Muslim doctor, and lastly, a male non-Muslim doctor""

Comment: I believe that an answer for this question in the framework of Islam should start saying that husband should do their best to protect their wife intimacy and awra, If one know that his wife is going to be seen by man, then I personally believe that prior that getting children, the husband should do his required effort, save money so that the woman can be guaranteed a medical checkups by woman, until the man has the required money to ensure this, he should avoid impregnating his wife, Then if ever pregnancy happens, then it would be ok for him to see a male doctor,

Comment: but I believe just saying we are allowed to do this without making any effort on our side make the awra of a woman as if granted, regarding a couple having children, Islamqna says in https://islamqa.info/en/231777, "not one of the scholars said that it is obligatory for a couple to produce children", and if it is not obligatory to have children but obligatory to protect awra, I believe delaying pregnancy until a man has the capacity isn't a big problem

Comment: @Noor islamqa is not representing Islam per se. Islamqa and islamweb even say we don't need to seek a physician and it is recommended not to do it. And even in a non-Muslim country you may encounter Muslim physicians! My answer was general on the point that your worries are too excessive and exaggerated. You can keep your believe for yourself, but you can't make something haram which Allah made halal. You may also read [How to interpret Sufyan a-Thawri's statement on permission](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/49865/how-to-interpret-sufyan-a-thawris-statement-on-permission-in-fatwas)

Comment: I agree Islamqa does not represent Islam, as far as my beliefs are concerned, this is an open platform, we can share what our beliefs about something and they aren't necessary true and right, and if we don't share them, we will never if they are right/wrong, true/false. Regarding your answer, I appreciate it and even upvoted it and my comments were not meant to belittle it, as far as my worries are concerned, i don't consider them excessive, i bear the responsibility of my wife awra, it's not a little one considering what islam did to protect woman..

Comment: @Noor the point of my answer is your worries -which I actually respect- are no valid excuses for refusing to have children. As work arounds exist and you may seek them or get information on that topic. There are a lot of spouses who are not able to have children and would do whatever is possible to be able to have one.

Answer (score 0):

Brother I totally understand halal and haram, but you're thinking too much of this.

> Allah intends for you ease and does not intend for you hardship
>
> [Baqara 185](https://quran.com/2/185)

FWIW It is actually recommended to get married and **then have a family**. So while not wajib it is mustahhab. But do you really need someone to tell you that it's mustahab? It's in our nature.

> *تناكحوا تناسلوا تكاثروا*
>
> Get married, have kids, populate.
>
> From prophet Muhammad

We are social beings. And for most women they love, want and take pride and having children. Delaying that for this reason may have unexpected mental outcomes. Allah does not like that. Also if women age then they have less chances of bearing a child.

Aside from all that, do you very best to accomodate for her to be with a female practitioner. I'm 100% sure that you will find a female practitioner for her routine checkups.

In case of her labor, if you ask around before you'll know of which hospital has a higher chance of having female practitioners.

But at very worst case. If you did this all and then somehow you ended up with a male practitioner what are you going to do? So no we'll wait for a female doctor?

I person in our community actually did that. I did NOT end well for them. The child had health issues and but they couldn't blame the hospital because the refused service from the hospital.

Islam values life. That's why we're allowed to eat pig meat or non-halal meats when in danger. If you did all your effort to have your wife not see a male doctor and at the end it came to it then so be it. Don't forbid something for you which Allah has not forbidden (there is no explicit mention of what I'm saying, but in our religion, life has a very very high value. Obviously inferring.)

> He has only forbidden to you dead animals, blood, the flesh of swine,
> and that which has been dedicated to other than Allah . But whoever is
> forced [by necessity], neither desiring [it] nor transgressing [its
> limit], there is no sin upon him. Indeed, Allah is Forgiving and
> Merciful.
>
> [Baqara 173](https://quran.com/2/173)

Comment: Thank you for you answer brother, but I don't think you not answered the question, the question is, is a husband allowed to impregnate a woman if he knows he does his wife will be consulted by a male gynecologist ? Either its a Yes for some reasons or no for some other reasons, Also you mention its natural for us to have children, it's true, at the same time it's natural for a man not be able to bear that his wife intimate parts will be touched by a male, among these two natures, which one is more natural is subjective, but my question is about what fiqh says,

Comment: And my answer is yes. Because whatever you do you may end up with a male doctor. Even if your in a Muslim country your wife playing volleyball can lead to a serious injury around the hip. What are you going to do then? Just not allow your wife to have a normal life because someone male doctor may see her or let her be in pain until you find a male?! Similarly if a women Muslim lady is dying in her pool are you not going to help her? Or condemn her because she went to the pool? Life has to go through. Having children is recommended it's not like your going to  Bahamas or your going snowboarding

Comment: If someone is dying, the case changes completely, then it would mean that saving her life becomes obligatory, that's why in my question, I specified the case even before pregnancy, because if a woman fall pregnant and the man has no means, then there is no other solution, abortion isn't allowed, so seeing a male doctor becomes understandable, otherwise, i still doubt...

Comment: All I am saying is what your thinking is not much different than not playing volleyball. Just do you very best. I was exactly in your shoes. I have kids myself.